# System service "Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?"

Tags: shell-script, scripting, linux-mint, services

```
/home/matthew/@/Sync/FreeFileSync "/home/matthew/@/Sync/Backup.ffs_batch"
```

If I manually run the above, it works, but it doesn't if I run it via the following service:

```
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ cat /lib/systemd/system/Testing1.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/matthew/@/Sync/FreeFileSync "/home/matthew/@/Sync/Backup.ffs_batch"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The error is shown below:

```
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ sudo systemctl status Testing1.service
[sudo] password for matthew: 
● Testing1.service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/Testing1.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-07-09 14:14:33 HKT; 1s ago
Process: 10255 ExecStart=/home/matthew/@/Sync/FreeFileSync /home/matthew/@/Sync/Backup.ffs_batch (code=exited, status=25
Main PID: 10255 (code=exited, status=255)

Jul 09 14:14:33 matthew-pc systemd[1]: Started Testing1.service.
Jul 09 14:14:33 matthew-pc FreeFileSync[10255]: 14:14:33: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
Jul 09 14:14:33 matthew-pc systemd[1]: Testing1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jul 09 14:14:33 matthew-pc systemd[1]: Testing1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How should I solve "**Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps:

1. Your service file must go into `/etc/systemd/user`. Execute `mv /etc/systemd/system/Testing1.service /etc/systemd/user/` for that.
2. Use the *user mode* of *systemd*. Execute `systemctl --user start Testing1.service` from your user account (not *root*) to start your service.

**Explication** *systemd* has two running modes, the *system mode* and *user mode*. The *system mode* is launched before that the user log into his session, so there is no graphical session at this point. *FreeFileSync* and *ReadTimeSync* needs access to the graphical *X11* display, so they can't be running *via* the *system mode*. In the *user mode*, *systemd* know about the user graphical session and use it (**only if** the shell that execute the command belongs to the user and his graphical environment). More details can be found [in the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd/User) or [on StackOverflow](https://superuser.com/questions/729338/autostart-gtk-application-with-systemd).

Comment: On another forum, someone has already provided a simple solution: adding `Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/matthew/.Xauthority"` under `[Service]`. However, I have another problem. In "Backup.ffs_batch", there is " <PostSyncCommand Condition="Completion">sudo eject /dev/sdb</PostSyncCommand>". However, after files have been backed up (i.e. "Completion"), the sudo command cannot be run. The error messages are " sudo[5666]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed" and "sudo[5666]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [matthew]". Is there a way to fix the error?

Comment: You wrote “In the user mode, _systemd_ know about the user graphical session and use it”. Am I right in thinking that  `Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/matthew/.Xauthority"` is what “systemd” needs to know in order to run FreeFileSync?

Comment: You're right, *systemd* **must** know about `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`. However, from my *systemd* and *X* experience, I think it's a very bad practice to hardcode in your service file a user home path and a display number. If you change for another user name/home, your service is broken. More problematic, if your graphical session is opened on another display (because the first are locked or another session is already running), your service is also broken. Then, I really suggest you to use the *systemd* *user mode* that will know about your user session.

Comment: To run a command after the backup with *FreeFileSync*, I don't recommend to use `sudo` inside the *FreeFileSync* configuration file. Instead, you can use the `ExecStartPost` clause of `[Service]` section of your *systemd* service. This clause is used to execute a command after the ending of your service, here, after your backup.

Comment: **`ExecStartPost=/home/matthew/@/Sync/Eject_a_device`** does not work. The "Eject_a_device" script contains only two line: **`#!/bin/bash`** and **`sudo eject /dev/sdb`**.

Comment: Hm. *systemd* does not execute *ExecStartPost* if the *ExecStart* has been detected as failed. To bypass and eliminate this idea, add a `-` prefix to your command, .e.g. `ExecStartPost=-/full/path/to/a/script`. If it doesn't work, check the execution your service with `sudo journalctl --catalog`, search for your service name to see what happened.

Comment: Things are different now. "**ExecStart**" can be run successfully (i.e. files can be backed up) as long as "**ExecStartPost**" has been deleted.  If "**ExecStartPost**" exists, "**ExecStart**" will fail because the device has already been ejected. "**ExecStartPost**" will eject the device before "**ExecStart**" has finished the job.

Comment: I have just tried your "**/etc/systemd/user**" method, and it works.